# For, html, and beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, hyperlink, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do something like:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2,unicodedata
import re

for x in range(1,105):

html_page = urllib2.urlopen('http://xxxxxx/BUSCAR/H=1;OR=5;ST=;LIST_ART_PAGENUMBER='+str(x)+';/Dxxxxx.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://xxxxxx/PRODUCTO/PROD_ID")}):
    print link.get('href')
```

to extract links. I correctly extract links. But I want to extract the range of 1 to 105

but this doesn't work!

```
error: expected an indented block
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent when you start the for loop. Try this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2,unicodedata
import re

for x in range(1,105):

    html_page = urllib2.urlopen('http://xxxxxx/BUSCAR/H=1;OR=5;ST=;LIST_ART_PAGENUMBER='+str(x)+';/Dxxxxx.aspx')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
    for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href':re.compile("^http://xxxxxx/PRODUCTO/PROD_ID")}):
         print link.get('href')
```

Comment: Hi @DamianPerez you're welcome. This is very basic and nothing much. Keep learning! You can accept the answer if you find it satisfactory.